# Set theory corollary proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am given that 
$$ran\, H\subseteq dom\, G $$
and that 
$$dom\,(G\circ H)\subseteq dom\, H$$
I need to prove that 
$$dom\, H = dom (G\circ H)$$
I know that I am just being stupid but I am really having trouble proving this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prove

- dom $H \subseteq$ dom $G\circ H$
- dom $G\circ H \subseteq$ dom $H$.

The second one is a given, so you only need to prove the first. The only way that dom $H \not\subseteq$ dom $G\circ H$ could occur was if there was some $x\in$ dom $H$ for which $H(x)$ was not in dom $G$. But this possibility is ruled out by ran $H\subseteq $ dom $G$.